# Editing a list that can be filtered while editing. Save edits that are not visible?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

We have a long list with accounts for which users can set permissions through checkboxes in this list. 
But users can also filter the list (say with a search query). 
But what if a user sets permissions and then filters the list so that the persmissions for that item are not visible anymore? Should that invisible permission be saved or not? Or is there a nicer UI pattern?

Answer (score 1):

**The invisible permissions must be saved**. Because from the user perspective , the user will go on giving permission and at some point if the user cant find a particular name he/she might resort to filtering and this should not cause the already given permissions to be lost.

**Alternative design:**
You can use [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin to do this in a more efficient way. The multiple select option in this helps user to see all the selected options thus far at one place. User can keep adding to this list , and then apply filter as and when needed

The design will look like this [image]